How to record upcoming supply
I am relatively new to the Salesforce world. I currently have an issue on my plate that I would like to ask you for help with.
I have an opportunity that should cover several things:
Manufacturing: A customer comes to us and wants to manufacture a product in series, so he has to pay development costs, which we record in fields directly on the opportunity.
This is where it gets interesting:
Deliveries in the future: The customer tells us what the sales volume will be this year, next year and in two years. We would like to record this and add it to the opportunity amount. It would be nice to use product schedules, but the problem with that is, that we actually didn't sell the product yet, so I'm not sure if opportunity products are the right way to do it.
We then also need a forecast on revenue (opportunity amount) and a forecast for our manufacture, so that they know what will be produced.

I have an opportunity that should cover several things is a XY problem. The keywords you want to google are "cost-based pricing", e.g. CPQ is one SF product that does it. Your best bet is to find a 3rd party on App Exchange that handles this.
